# Tensorflow image reshaping

Tags: tensorflow, image-resizing

length of train image set 40
X_train shape: (40, 32, 32, 3)
y_train shape: (40,)
Im getting this error: Cannot feed value of shape (40, 32, 32, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder_17:0', which has shape '(1, 32, 32, 3)'

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 32, 32, 3])

c1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=x, activation=tf.nn.relu, filters=32, 
kernel_size=[5,5], padding='VALID', strides=1)
p1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=c1, pool_size=[2,2], strides=2)

c2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=p1, activation=tf.nn.relu, filters=64, 
kernel_size=[5,5], padding='VALID', strides=1)
p2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=c2, pool_size=[2,2], strides=2)

f = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(p2) 

fc1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=f, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu) 

logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs = fc1, units=2)

tf.layers.dropout(inputs = fc1, rate = 0.4) 



epochs = 50

for i in range(epochs):
    sess.run([trainer], feed_dict={x:X_train/255., y:y_train})
    [acc, l] = sess.run([accuracy, loss], feed_dict={x:X_train/255., y:y_train})
    print('Epoch %d - Loss: | %.2f Accuracy: %.2f'%(i,np.mean(l),acc))
```

Comment: You can try allowing for batching in your placeholder. For that you have to leave the size of the batch [*1*, 32, 32, 3] unspecified by setting it to None. It should look smth like that 'x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 32, 32, 3])'

Comment: I tries. Still the error persists

Comment: Ok i tries resetting the graph and Set it None. Now it works . Thanks man ♥️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have placeholder dimensions and input dimensions match. So you will have to set placeholder_17 to  `(40, 32, 32, 3)` or iteratively feed in each of the image into placeholder_17 with dimension  `(1, 32, 32, 3)`.